# Scraping div tag with image in Python and BeautifuLSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a webpage with Python and BeautifuLSoup. I have a variable called `aaatag` which saves this tag in html:

```html
<div data-tooltip class="has-tip radius piva-badge" title="partida of the page"></div>
```

My problem is that this shows an image stored in `/image/sprite.png`. The image is 30x60 and it only gets the first 30x30 when the image is activated, and the second 30x30 when it's deactivated.

So the background-position changes from 30-0 to 30-30.

Is there any way to get to see the background position using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: You'd have to parse the CSS stylesheets that apply to the page. I am not aware of any Python CSS parsers that let you find what rules apply to a given HTML element, however.

Comment: But you haven't given us enough context to even *begin* answering this question; just posting the `<div>` doesn't give us any context, like what CSS stylesheets are applied, or if there are parent elements that are part of the CSS selector that applies here.

Comment: yeah Martijn, that's what I wanted to know. So I need to scrap the css file also? or something like that? I don't really know how this works since I only used BeautifulSoup to scrap the html code

Comment: Yes, you need to load the CSS, then parse it, then somehow figure out what rules applied to the div. The last step is missing in this chain, as far as I know.